# Google Timelines and an Array of Dates

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am creating an array and I have Dates along with Country (It's coming out of my database).  How do I create my AnnotatedTimeLine based off this data?   I get the error "First column must contain date, or date and time" with my current set up

Creating Array

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$callDate = strtotime($r[CALLDATEEST]);
$convertedCallDate = date("Y-m-d",$callDate);
$pieChartArray .= "[$convertedCallDate, '$r[COUNTRY]'],\n";
}
$pieChartArray  = substr(trim($pieChartArray), 0, -1);
?>
```

Function

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Call times', 'Country'],
            <?php echo $pieChartArray; ?>
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to input the dates as date objects.  The easiest way to do that is to use the DataTable JSON structure for your data:

```
$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Call times'),
        array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Country')
    ),
    'rows' => array()
);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $callDate = strtotime($r[CALLDATEEST]);
    $year = (int) date("Y",$callDate);
    $month = ((int) date("m",$callDate)) - 1; // convert months to javascript's 0-indexed months
    $day = (int) date("d",$callDate);

    $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day)"),
        array('v' => $r[COUNTRY])
    ));
}
```

then in javascript:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not not too familiar with parseInt, I am getting an error Call to undefined function parseInt()