# Data must contain two columns Google Charts

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am attempting to build a Annotated Time line (Google Chart API), and I am unable to correct this.  I'm getting the error "Data must contain two columns".  Does anyone see any problems?

Javascript

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>);
        var options = {
            title: ''
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(document.getElementById('trend_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {displayAnnotations: true});
    }
```

Then my PHP

```
$sth = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT( * ) AS callCount, CALLTIMEEST,TAKEN FROM DAYCALLS WHERE REGION = 1 GROUP BY CALLTIMEEST,TAKEN ");
$pieChartArray = "";
$data = array(
'cols' => array(
    array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'Call times'),
    array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'TAKEN')
    ),
'rows' => array()
);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$callDate = strtotime($r['CALLTIMEEST']);
$year = (int) date("Y",$callDate);
$month = ((int) date("m",$callDate)) - 1; // convert months to javascript's 0-indexed months
$day = (int) date("d",$callDate);

$data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
    array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day)"),
    array('v' => $r['TAKEN'])
    ));
```

}

Comment: you're passing an array of objects, not an array of arrays like google wants. (php doesn't know the diff)

Comment: That's the guidance I was given to do here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693551/google-timelines-and-an-array-of-dates.  Was I guided wrong?

Comment: that link points to someone using an array of arrays, like you're supposed to...  keep in mind that PHP's array() makes both Arrays and Objects when converted to JSON. just get rid of the keys and you'll be fine.

Comment: That was original post, and it wasn't working.

Comment: $data['rows'][] = array( Date($year, $month, $day), $r['TAKEN'] );

Comment: Not sure what I am suppose to do with that line.. replace that with what I currently have for $data?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm still getting that error Data must contain at least two columns.

Comment: post the json your're feeding the chart, it should be in shape of [['a','b'],[1,2],[3,4]]

Comment: The PHP you have in your question should generate the correct DataTable JSON structure.  Update your question with the output of the `echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` call (open the page in a browser and view the page source to see it).